# JAXB2 Removing standalone="yes" on XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to remove the standalone="yes" on my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

I tried with this code:

```
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);            
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">");
```

The result on XML - Duplicate information:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
```

Does anyone know how to remove standalone="yes"?

Marshall code:

```
        try {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataToXML.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\">");

        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(xml, writer);

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
        
        marshaller.marshal(xml, new File("test.xml"));

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice is not to use this JAXB.Fragment true. It can result into nullpointers on sax level if your document is not actually a fragment. For example a case whereby you have multiple fragments in your object.

First lets do some marshalling, you can choose multiple objecttypes to marshall to. But in general you can marshall to a DomResult this allows us to edit it later using a transformer.

---

## Marshall

```
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        DOMResult destinationXml = new DOMResult();
        marshaller.marshall(objectToMarshall, destinationXmlResult);
```

## Transform

```
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        // make sure you disable the external access, for security reasons..
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "no");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlResult.getNode()), new StreamResult(writer));
        return writer.toString();
```

If Transform is to much, replace will do also

## Replace

```
final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshall(object, new StreamResult(writer));
return writer.replaceAll("standalone=\"yes\"", "")
```

Hope this helps.

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html

and
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta/xml/bind/marshaller

See: [OutputKeys](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html)

Answer (score -1):

XSLT transformation to the rescue.

It is possible to control almost any XML aspect via `<xsl:output .../>` clause attributes.

One of them is **standalone** = 'yes' or 'no'

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```